# HTML 5 Bootstrap System Grid

Tags: html5, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-3, bootstrap

Eu preciso fazer com o grid system se possível o exemplo da imagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

No exemplo acima, preciso apenas da formatação, onde cada evento é um 'div' com um tamanho dinâmico, e o de baixo cola no de cima como mostra o exemplo. Tentei utilizar o código abaixo para chegar como no exemplo, mas quando atinge o 'col-12' ele quebra a linha e fica tudo 'reto' na mesma linha, ficando desproporcional, ou seja, se fosse no exemplo abaixo, a cada 4 eventos, ficariam todos em uma linha reta.

Abaixo é o código que tentei utilizar para chegar no exemplo abaixo:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-8">.col-xs-12 .col-sm-6 .col-md-8</div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">.col-xs-6 .col-md-4</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4">.col-xs-6 .col-sm-4</div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4">.col-xs-6 .col-sm-4</div>
  <!-- Optional: clear the XS cols if their content doesn't match in height -->
  <div class="clearfix visible-xs-block"></div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4">.col-xs-6 .col-sm-4</div>
</div>
```

Obrigado pela ajuda.

Answer (score 1):

Use o plugin [*Jquery.isotope*](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/):

```js
$(document).ready(function()
{ 
  $('.grid').isotope({
   itemSelector: '.rows',
        sortBy : 'original-order'
  });
});
```

```css
.rows {
  margin: 2px 2px 2px 2px;
  width: 192px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.isotope/3.0.1/isotope.pkgd.js"></script>


<div class="grid">
  <div class="rows">
    <img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/9b/03/28/9b032800c0034f2690223e12ff014809.jpg" border="0" style="width:190px" /> 
  </div>  
  <div class="rows">
    <img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/ae/27/88/ae27883794e4a96e9d9a4cb2b2d1313b.jpg" border="0" style="width:190px"/>
  </div>
  <div class="rows">
    <img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/9b/03/28/9b032800c0034f2690223e12ff014809.jpg" border="0" style="width:190px" /> 
  </div>   
  <div class="rows">
    <img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/ae/27/88/ae27883794e4a96e9d9a4cb2b2d1313b.jpg" border="0" style="width:190px"/>
  </div>  
   <div class="rows">
    <img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/9b/03/28/9b032800c0034f2690223e12ff014809.jpg" border="0" style="width:190px" /> 
  </div>  
  <div class="rows">
    <img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/ae/27/88/ae27883794e4a96e9d9a4cb2b2d1313b.jpg" border="0" style="width:190px"/>
  </div> 
  <div class="rows">
    <img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/ae/27/88/ae27883794e4a96e9d9a4cb2b2d1313b.jpg" border="0" style="width:190px"/>
  </div>
  <div class="rows">
    <img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/9b/03/28/9b032800c0034f2690223e12ff014809.jpg" border="0" style="width:190px" /> 
  </div>
</div>
```

As classes do [bootstrap-3](/questions/tagged/bootstrap-3) deverão ser removidas, o [*Jquery.isotope*](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/) fará esse papel inclusive quando diminuir ou aumentar a página.

Comment: Show, exatamente isso que estava procurando. Obrigado!

Comment: @lfabra se for util aceite a resposta.